# Can't understand this error "Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput' "

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, svm, decision-tree

I am trying to run several machine learning algorithms on a dataset to predict whether the salary/income is greater than 50k or less than equal to 50k. I made a function and am passing the values to it, with different size sample sets of 1% samples, 10% samples and 100% samples.
I am getting an unknown error 'Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput''
I don't know what this error is.

I tried changing the classification algorithms I used but no use. It displays the same error for all the alogrithms.

```
from sklearn.metrics import fbeta_score, accuracy_score

def train_predict (learner, sample_size, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    results = {}
    start = time()
    learner = learner.fit(X_train[:sample_size], y_train)
    end = time()
    results['train_time'] = end - start

    start = time()
    predictions_test = learner.predict(X_test)
    predictions_train = learner.predict(X_train[:sample_size])
    end = time()

    results['pred_time'] = end - start
    results['acc_train'] = accuracy_score(X_train[:sample_size], y_train[:sample_size])
    results['acc_test'] = accuracy_score[X_test, y_test]
    results['f_train'] = fbeta_score(X_train[:sample_size], y_train[:sample_size], beta = 1)
    resutts['f_test'] = fbeta_score(X_test, y_test, beta = 1)
    print("{} trained on {} samples. ".format(learner.__class__.__name__, sample_size))
    return results

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC

clf_A = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf_B = GaussianNB()
clf_C = SVC()

samples_100 = len(X_train)       #taking 100% i.e. all the data in training set
samples_10 = int(len(X_train)*.1) # taking 10% of the training data
samples_1 = int(len(X_train)*.01) #taking 1% of the training data

results= {}
for clf in [clf_A, clf_B, clf_C]:
    clf_name = clf.__class__.__name__
    results[clf_name] = {}
    for i, samples in enumerate([samples_1, samples_10, samples_100]):
        results[clf_name][i] = \
        train_predict(clf, samples, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
vs.evaluate(results, accuracy, fscore)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-e06d42fbd15b> in <module>
      5     for i, samples in enumerate([samples_1, samples_10, samples_100]):
      6         results[clf_name][i] = \
----> 7         train_predict(clf, samples, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
      8 vs.evaluate(results, accuracy, fscore)

<ipython-input-62-4484b803a707> in train_predict(learner, sample_size, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
      2     results = {}
      3     start = time()
----> 4     learner = learner.fit(X_train[:sample_size], y_train)
      5     end = time()
      6     results['train_time'] = end - start

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    799             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    800             check_input=check_input,
--> 801             X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
    802         return self
    803 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    138 
    139         if is_classification:
--> 140             check_classification_targets(y)
    141             y = np.copy(y)
    142 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    169     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    170                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 171         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
    172 
    173 

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput'
```

I want this code to run and show the accuracy and other metrics of these algorithms for this datasets.

P.S. I know the code is too long and cumbersome but please take efforts to go through it and let me know the solution. I am newbie in this machine learning domain. Any help will be highly appreciated.

P.S. Please don't mark this question as duplicate I have already been through similar questions and tried all that was suggested there but in vain. It wan't of any use to me.

Comment: Please show a sample of your *labels* `y_train`

Comment: X_train consists of 100+ features and y_train is a single string i.e. '<=50k' and '>50k'. Here, I am trying to predict whether the income is greater than 50,000 or less than 50,000 from multiple features like education, occupation, matrital status, etc.

Comment: I have the same message error in this line: ```X_SMOTE, y_SMOTE = smote.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)``` (source: https://github.com/dyt08/diabetes-prediction/blob/main/diabetes.ipynb) Does anyone know what is wrong?  I am searching stackoverflow + google solution for 2 days... Nothing works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got the error the problem was with the way I was sampling the data sets.
I changed the sampling code using frac attribute and the error disappeared.

```
samples_100 = df.sample(frac = 1)      #taking 100% i.e. all the data in training set
samples_10 = df.sample(frac = .1)      #taking 10% of the training data
samples_1 = df.sample(frac = .01)      #taking 1% of the training data
```

Comment: Sadly, that still don't explain source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that unknown error 'Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput'' because, if you see in your code

`train_predict(clf, samples, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)`

This needs to be rearranged as

`train_predict(clf, samples, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)`

As we are splitting data between train and test for variables x and y, order is important to split and assign data properly.

I was facing the same problem and it worked for me.